# Problem when using arduino nano as isp and atmega328p-pu

Tags: microcontroller

I am using an Arduino Nano as an ISP programmer. And I want to program my Atmega328p-pu with it. I followed this tutorial: [Using Arduino nano as an isp programmer](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-nano-as-an-isp-programmer/)

But I want to use internal 8MHz clock. So I remove the crystal and caps. (In the picture  shown below ) [image]

When I use avrdude to program my chip there is a problem:

> device signature = **0x000000** or **0xffffff**

Sometimes it responds a wrong signature like **0x0000ff**. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to use internal 8MHz clock. So I remove crystal ,caps. (In picture shown below )

Apart from removing caps you should also be changing the fuses for selecting the internal clock source and disabling the clock/8 fuse

---

Try to select a lower baud rate in avrdude, That might help as well